# What is the proof of of (N–1) + (N–2) + (N–3) + ... + 1= N*(N–1)/2

Tags: formula, proof

I got this formula from a data structure book in the bubble sort algorithm.

I know that we are (n-1) * (n times), but why the division by 2?

Can anyone please explain this to me or give the detailed proof for it.

Thank you

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: ...is for research-level math questions only.

Comment: @PascalThivent: This question would be closed within seconds on mathoverflow.

Comment: @Stephan, that's the formula if the `N` is added on the left side. If it's not, one `N` is missing, so `2N` should be subtracted in the numerator.

Comment: Off-topic? - has algorithm analysis got nothing to do with programming? As Skystar says, the context is the analysis of an algorithm.

Comment: Because one quick way to add up numbers is to list the numbers ascending, then below that descending. Your realise all the time you're adding up N+1s (first pair 1,n, 2nd pair 2,n-1...) n times. Hence n*(n+1). You've actually summed all the numbers twice, so you half it to get the answer.

Comment: @rjh @sepp2k Sorry then, forget what I said.

Comment: That's too basic for mathoverflow.net; it's considered A-level Maths/maybe GCSE here in the UK.

Comment: Stephan202: Only if the series starts at `n`.

Comment: Wow, I have serious objections to this being closed.

Comment: @litb, @Ken: You're right. I didn't observe that `N` itself isn't included (usually it is, with this problem statement). Doh!

Comment: This is at it's heart a math question. Basically an algebraic identity. That doesn't kill it as a SO topic, but my personal benchmark for math questions belonging on SO is "Will the math be performed by a program *or* will the math be translated into code?" In this case the answer is "No.", so I would also vote for a close as off topic. YMMV.

Comment: Are you me?!?! I was just looking this up, you worded exactly as I was thinking about :D

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [triangle numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Thanks

I liked these techniques in explaining the proof of this formula especially technique number three, which can be found at http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/

Answer (score 49):

`(N-1) + (N-2) +...+ 2 + 1` is a sum of N-1 items. Now reorder the items so, that after the first comes the last, then the second, then the second to last, i.e. `(N-1) + 1 + (N-2) + 2 +..`. The way the items are ordered now you can see that each of those pairs is equal to N (N-1+1 is N, N-2+2 is N). Since there are N-1 items, there are (N-1)/2 such pairs. So you're adding N (N-1)/2 times, so the total value is `N*(N-1)/2`.

Answer (score 31):

Start with the triangle...

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
```

representing 1+2+3+4 so far. Cut the triangle in half along one dimension...

```
     *
    **
  * **
 ** **
```

Rotate the smaller part 180 degrees, and stick it on top of the bigger part...

```
    **
    * 

     *
    **
    **
    **
```

Close the gap to get a rectangle.

At first sight this only works if the base of the rectangle has an even length - but if it has an odd length, you just cut the middle column in half - it still works with a half-unit-wide twice-as-tall (still integer area) strip on one side of your rectangle.

Whatever the base of the triangle, the width of your rectangle is `(base / 2)` and the height is `(base + 1)`, giving `((base + 1) * base) / 2`.

However, my `base` is your `n-1`, since the bubble sort compares a pair of items at a time, and therefore iterates over only (n-1) positions for the first loop.

Answer (score 9):

Try to make pairs of numbers from the set. The first + the last; the second + the one before last. It means n-1 + 1; n-2 + 2. The result is always n. And since you are adding two numbers together, there are only (n-1)/2 pairs that can be made from (n-1) numbers.

So it is like (N-1)/2 * N.

Answer (score 6):

> I know that we are (n-1) * (n times), but why the division by 2?

It's only `(n - 1) * n` if you use a naive bubblesort. You can get a significant savings if you notice the following:

- After each compare-and-swap, the largest element you've encountered will be in the last spot you were at.
- After the first pass, the largest element will be in the last position; after the k<sup>th</sup> pass, the k<sup>th</sup> largest element will be in the k<sup>th</sup> last position.

Thus you don't have to sort the whole thing every time: you only need to sort n - 2 elements the second time through, n - 3 elements the third time, and so on. That means that the total number of compare/swaps you have to do is `(n - 1) + (n - 2) + ...`. This is an **[arithmetic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_series)**, and the equation for the total number of times is (n - 1)*n / 2.

**Example:** if the size of the list is N = 5, then you do 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10 swaps -- and notice that 10 is the same as 4 * 5 / 2.

Comment: But it is also written that n(n - 1)/2 or O(n^2)  or n^2. So square of n i.e square of 5 is 25. But n(n-1)/2 is 10. So how is this possible?

Comment: @Harinder: "or O(n^2) or n^2 ...". No, O(n^2) == n^2 is not correct. `n^2 + 1,000,000` is also `O(n^2)` but is clearly not equal to `n^2`.

Comment: This is what I don't understand. For example look at this http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/sorting/bubble/section1.rhtml . It also says in the end that average and worst case are n^2

Comment: And also is this correct n(n - 1)/2 or O(n^2)?? If so how did it become O(n^2)

Comment: @Harinder: You should ask a separate SO question. Comments aren't really good for answering things at length.

Answer (score 2):

Sum of arithmetical progression

(A1+AN)/2*N = (1 + (N-1))/2*(N-1) = N*(N-1)/2

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common proof.  One way to prove this is to use mathematical induction.  Here is a link: http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/~larryc/proofs/proofs.mathinduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Assume n=2. Then we have 2-1 = 1 on the left side and 2*1/2 = 1 on the right side.

Denote f(n) = (n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+1

Now assume we have tested up to n=k. Then we have to test for n=k+1.

on the left side we have k+(k-1)+(k-2)+...+1, so it's f(k)+k

On the right side we then have (k+1)*k/2 = (k^2+k)/2 = (k^2 +2k - k)/2 = k+(k-1)*k/2 = k*f(k)

So this have to hold for every k, and this concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof by induction, considering `N` terms, but it's the same for `N - 1`:

For `N = 0` the formula is obviously true.

Suppose `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = N(N + 1) / 2` is true for some natural `N`.

We'll prove `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N + (N + 1) = (N + 1)(N + 2) / 2` is also true by using our previous assumption:

`1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N + (N + 1) = (N(N + 1) / 2) + (N + 1)
                               = (N + 1)((N / 2) + 1)
                               = (N + 1)(N + 2) / 2`.

So the formula holds for all `N`.

Comment: "Suppose P(N) is true for all natural N". That's not a correct proof by induction. You're aiming to prove P(N) => P(N+1), so you should assume P(N) is true for *some* N. If you assume it for *all* N, then you beg the question.