# If my method with time complexity O(n^2) uses another method with time complexity O(n) does its time complexity change?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

The `what` method has a time complexity of O(n^2) and it uses the method `f` with time complexity of O(n). I need to calculate the overall time complexity of method `what`. Do I also take in account the time complexity of method `f`, so overall the time complexity of method `what` would be O(n^2 * n = n^3), or does each method take care of its own time complexity, so in this case the method `what` will stay at time complexity O(n^2)?

```
private static int f (int[]a, int low, int high)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (int i=low; i<=high; i++)
        res += a[i];
    return res;
}

public static int what (int []a)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; j<a.length; j++)
        {
            int c = f(a, i, j);
            if (c%2 == 0)
            {
                if (j-i+1 > temp)
                    temp = j-i+1;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Otherwise you could put the inner loop into a separate function and "magically" make your `what` function faster. Obviously that won't happen.

Comment: I am complete noob in algorithm complexity estimation but Are you sure your `what` has O(n^2) ? There is still inner loop that shifts start position every outer loop iteration.

Comment: @AlexeyR. yes it's O(n^2) : `n + (n-1) + .. + 2 + 1 = (n+1)n/2`  [here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483918/what-is-the-proof-of-of-n-1-n-2-n-3-1-nn-1-2)

Comment: @AloisChristen: this is plain wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how so ? could you elaborate where it's wrong ? I'm talking about the `what` function only, without the added complexity of the `f` function.

Comment: @AloisChristen: without the added complexity ??? `f` is called, you can't ignore it.

Comment: You *can* express time complexity in terms of function calls to `f`, if explicit about it. The helper function can be viewed as a black box / oracle, and it can be useful especially if we don't know its complexity or if it might vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Complexity give high level estimate that how much time it takes to execute. So `Yes` you need to include every line of code which take time i.e time complexity of `f` function also. It is also take time.

`What` function has two loops and and one loop inside `f` function which is being called from `what` function.

`Let calculate Time Complexity`

Time complexity of `f` function when it is being first time from `what' function when i=0 and j incremented by inner loop from 0 to n

```
      1. When i=0 and j=0 then execute one time 
      2. when i=0 and j=1 then execute two time
      3. when i=0 and j=2 then execute three time
soon on 
      .
      .
      .
      n. When i=0 and j=n then  execute n time

SO
 Total = 1+ 2+3+4.......+n
       = n(n+1)/2 = sum of n consecutive numbers

Thus

    TC of `f` Function execute first time from J loop from 0 t0 n =n(n+1)/2
```

But `i` loop execute n times so

`Total Time Complexity of whole execution/ your program equalvent to n*[n*(n+1)/2 + ((n-1)n)/2) + ((n-2)(n-1))/2+ ...... + 1] ~ that means TC equlavent to` **O(n^3)**

Comment: Your last line is wrong.

Comment: How it is wrong? It is correct. that is the main line to understand :). j loop execution is already included in n(n+1)/2. So only execution of i need to include that is n.

Comment: Plese make sure that you are right before using irony. Your `n` "inner" varies and in reality the total number of calls is equal to `n³/6` (dominant term).

Comment: i got it. what you are saying.

Comment: Can you please explain how this `n³/6` come like i explained using math so it is easy to understand.

Comment: Check the formula for the sum of squares.

Comment: got it. Thanks man. I changed according to that . use equalvent to

Comment: This is still wrong. ~ means asymptotically equal to, and the constant coefficient matters. You just missed my comment.